# How to get what is new and recent changes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

Is there a button or link to explanation of the changes? Like this revision at this date, introduced these changes.

Is there a voting somewhere for features requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check  the official list of new features and various changes to Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network:
[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

Also, check all the recent questions tagged [status-completed]:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed

For voting, simply vote +1 on feature requests you want:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request

Comment: I have seen the question regarding recent feature changes, but I expected it to see it like a link somewhere - not as a question/answer

Answer (score 1):

This [question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) details all recent changes to the Stack Exchange Network.

New features are either posted on this site by Moderators tagged as [`discussion`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) i.e. We are thinking of implementing of this idea what features would you like to see

Or they are posted by members of the community tagged as [`feature-request`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There is no definitive page or wiki with a complete list where new feature are proposed and accepted (apart from questions on this site obviously)

Comment: As @augustin as mentioned - also check out [Status-Completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)